# Access grandchildren with beautifull soup select

Tags: python, css, xml, beautifulsoup

I have been struggling with this one for quite some time.

Given the following XML file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<html>
    <body>
        <feed xml:base="https:newrecipes.org"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
            xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
            <id>https://recipes.com</id>
            <title>Cuisine</title>
            <updated>2020-08-10T08:48:56.800Z</updated>
            <link href="Cuisine" rel="self" title="Cuisine"/>
            <entry>
                <id>https://www.cuisine.org(53198770598313985)</id>
                <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="DefaultNamespace.Cuisine"></category>
                <title></title>
                <updated>1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</updated>
                <content type="application/xml">
                    <m:properties>
                        <d:id m:type="Edm.Int64">53198770598313985</d:id>
                        <d:name m:type="Edm.String">American</d:name>
                    </m:properties>
                </content>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <id>https://www.cuisine.org(53198770598313986)</id>
                <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="DefaultNamespace.Cuisine"></category>
                <title></title>
                <updated>1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</updated>
                <content type="application/xml">
                    <m:properties>
                        <d:id m:type="Edm.Int64">53198770598313986</d:id>
                        <d:name m:type="Edm.String">Asian</d:name>
                    </m:properties>
                </content>
            </entry>
        </feed>
      </body>
     </html>
```

Using BeautifulSoup I came up with the following solution in order to get the id's from the entry tag using the child combinator.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
# Make a BS object to parse the xml string.
xml_soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_string, features="lxml")

# Use the child combinator to select the ids that are direct descendants of entry
cuisine_ids_unparsed = xml_soup.select("entry > content")

# Get the ids from the Tag value using regex.
# Then return the first occurrence of the regex found.
cuisine_ids = [re.findall(r"\((.*)\)", cuisine_id.text)[0] for cuisine_id in cuisine_ids_unparsed]
```

This will return all the cuisine IDs in the file that are in the parentheses of the `<id>` tag. But I would also like to access the `properties` inside each `entry`. Because these contain both the id and the name of the cuisine without any parsing needed.
Unfortunately using the Child combinator (>) from css I can't go deeper and I was wondering if there was a better way, other than iterating over the elements to extract the value. Something like:

```
cuisine_ids_unparsed = xml_soup.select("entry > content > properties > id")
```

to retrieve all the ids and

```
cuisine_names_unparsed = xml_soup.select("entry > content > properties > name")
```

to retrieve all the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used a bit of @Andrej Kesely advice, but instead of `zip` you could do the following with regex.:

```
txt = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<html>
    <body>
        <feed xml:base="https:newrecipes.org"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
            xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
            <id>https://recipes.com</id>
            <title>Cuisine</title>
            <updated>2020-08-10T08:48:56.800Z</updated>
            <link href="Cuisine" rel="self" title="Cuisine"/>
            <entry>
                <id>https://www.cuisine.org(53198770598313985)</id>
                <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="DefaultNamespace.Cuisine"></category>
                <title></title>
                <updated>1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</updated>
                <content type="application/xml">
                    <m:properties>
                        <d:id m:type="Edm.Int64">53198770598313985</d:id>
                        <d:name m:type="Edm.String">American</d:name>
                    </m:properties>
                </content>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <id>https://www.cuisine.org(53198770598313986)</id>
                <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="DefaultNamespace.Cuisine"></category>
                <title></title>
                <updated>1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</updated>
                <content type="application/xml">
                    <m:properties>
                        <d:id m:type="Edm.Int64">53198770598313986</d:id>
                        <d:name m:type="Edm.String">Asian</d:name>
                    </m:properties>
                </content>
            </entry>
        </feed>
      </body>
</html>'''


xml_soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, features="xml")

properties_unparsed = xml_soup.select('entry > content > m|properties')

for prop in properties_unparsed:
    # Extract the id and name from the text of the property
    # The id is going to be a sequence of numbers
    # the name a sequence of letters.
    tup = re.match(r'(\d+)(\w+)', prop.text).groups()
    id_ = tup[0]
    name = tup[1]
    print(id_, name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()` function to *"tie"* the two tags together:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<html>
    <body>
        <feed xml:base="https:newrecipes.org"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
            xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
            <id>https://recipes.com</id>
            <title>Cuisine</title>
            <updated>2020-08-10T08:48:56.800Z</updated>
            <link href="Cuisine" rel="self" title="Cuisine"/>
            <entry>
                <id>https://www.cuisine.org(53198770598313985)</id>
                <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="DefaultNamespace.Cuisine"></category>
                <title></title>
                <updated>1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</updated>
                <content type="application/xml">
                    <m:properties>
                        <d:id m:type="Edm.Int64">53198770598313985</d:id>
                        <d:name m:type="Edm.String">American</d:name>
                    </m:properties>
                </content>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <id>https://www.cuisine.org(53198770598313986)</id>
                <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="DefaultNamespace.Cuisine"></category>
                <title></title>
                <updated>1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</updated>
                <content type="application/xml">
                    <m:properties>
                        <d:id m:type="Edm.Int64">53198770598313986</d:id>
                        <d:name m:type="Edm.String">Asian</d:name>
                    </m:properties>
                </content>
            </entry>
        </feed>
      </body>
</html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'xml')


for id_, name in zip(soup.select('entry > id'), soup.select('entry > content > m|properties > d|name')):
    print(re.search(r'\((.*?)\)', id_.text).group(1))
    print(name.text)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
53198770598313985
American
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
53198770598313986
Asian
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi Andrej! Thank you for your reply! Which Python version are you using? because this part: `soup.select('entry > content > m|properties > d|name')` returns an empty list for me :/

Comment: @Jack Make sure you use latest version of `bs4` and `xml` parser.